# My aspx pages are not rendering

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have developed a site, which is running fine on my local machine, but when I deployed it on live server.

1. Site root folder contents shows (directory browsing). I disabled it in web.config but no relief.....
2. When I click on .aspx pages. They do not render as HTML but their html is rendered as plain text.

What could be the reason?

Comment: There are bunch of reasons why your page can't render :)

Comment: Sounds to me like you've deployed it onto a machine that isn't running IIS.

Comment: or asp.net extension over iis is not setup/configure probably.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Some details about the IIS setup would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are just opening a file like from a directory (FTP), it is not hosted as a site

`Configure a virtual directory/website in your IIS server`

Make sure you have ASP.Net framework installed/configured with IIS ([`Aspnet_regiis.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.ASPX)) ([For windows 8 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676002/aspnet-regiis-exe-ir-does-not-work-on-windows-8))

Disable directory browsing