# This site can’t be reached [site]'s server DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10, iis-10

I'm running windows 10 and IIS version 1511(build 10586.164)
I have the default app pools running and the the default html displayed.
All of the other sites I've added give the same

> This site can’t be reached  [site]'s server DNS address could not be found. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I have used both visual studio 2012 and VS community 15.
The MVC 4 version of my project site had been running fine.

I am rebuilding in asp.net 4.61 MVC 5, to avoid the regular clashes with version types and stopping nuget updating me into a problem.

Using the default template for 4.61 MVC 5 I have an app that VS 15 can run.

The old site gives the following error and displays the favicon when run through VS and IIS.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>    error, so I'm parking it rather than getting archaeological.

Currently the sites are bound to a host name and port number, * IP Address.

I have checked SO questions:

[IIS 10 500.19 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845773/iis-10-500-19-error)
and 
[How to run ASP.NET MVC app in IIS 10 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756420/how-to-run-asp-net-mvc-app-in-iis-10-on-windows-10)

among others.

Any ideas?
It feels like it's something simple but I can't see it for trying.

Comment: VS15 is running them under IIS Express for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command line, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check security for your app folder? IIS_IUSRS must have read and execute rights, at least.