# ASP.NET MVC can not find controller on Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, publish

This is my first ASP.NET MVC project. It had been speedy development. However, when I deploy to the server, I just can't get the site to see the controller.

I did a test project. I just create an ASP.NET MVC project with no changes; published on to local IIS and it works. Same project on the server, didn't work.  I have an `index.html` on the root to see if the site is up. Indeed, it's up. I can see `index.html`. When I go `www.test.com/home/index` (which is my test site), I get HTTP error 404.0 - not found. The resource you are looking for has been removed had it's name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

`bin` folder does have project `dll`.

`App_start/routeconfig.cs` default url is point to home controller and the index action.

Project is straight out of the box. It should work.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Sincerely appreciated.

Comment: There can be a lot of reasons for this.  Have you tried searching for "asp.net mvc 404"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068770/getting-404-error-on-mvc-web-site

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is having the same issue.

There are so many reasons for error 404.

In my case, the network guy didn't install ASP.net framework.  See there's a fine line between developer and network guy.

It's not exactly what I was searching for, but it solved my problem.
[aspnet_regiis.exe -ir does not work on windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676002/aspnet-regiis-exe-ir-does-not-work-on-windows-8)