# (405) Method Not Allowed. WCF WebService

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, http-status-code-405

Introduction:

Hello, I am trying to set up a WCF web service on my local IIS 7.5 server, however after I finish the basic configurations I am unable to send data with a WinForms test client and it returns the error mentioned in the titles.
 I have already searched similar threads on this problem but i did not find anything that would fit my problem.

Data:

-Both the Wcf WebService and the test client where provided from a 3rd party

-They already work on another server and I am using the same versions

-I am probably doing something wrong when I enable or configure IIS

Request:

-I need to know what IIS features I need to enable/disable in order to install it correctly so I can use the Wcf WebService.(If that's the case).

-How to correctly configure the server in order to solve the above mentioned error.

My Configurations:

-After Installing IIS I changed the DefaulAppPool to .NET Framework v4.0.30.319; pipeline mode: Integrated. -Advanced Settings: Load User profile = False.

-Created a new Website named "WcfMicrocontrollerService" using DefaultAppPool.Binding; Type:http, IP adress: , port: 80

At this point I can access it trough a web browser, however when I use the test client to POST data to the service I get the following error: *"The remote server returned an unexpected response:(405) Method Not Allowed."*

Here are the data packets sent as recorded by Fiddler:
 Sent:

```
POST http://192.168.0.102/MicroControllerComSvc.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IMicroControllerComSvc/GetMicrocontrollerData"
Host: 192.168.0.102
Content-Length: 237
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetMicrocontrollerData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><microControllerData>1,1,1,1,2,2,1,0,100,300</microControllerData></GetMicrocontrollerData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Received:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: private
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2016 10:44:44 GMT
Content-Length: 5671
```

And here's the body: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2237590/405.html

This seems to indicate that I should take a look in handler mappings but I have no idea what to edit there.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok so after a very brief search about your issue I found the following question
[WCF on IIS8; *.svc handler mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116134/wcf-on-iis8-svc-handler-mapping-doesnt-work)

Ignoring the fact that the question is about IIS 8, are you running Windows or Windows Server?

If you are using Windows go to...

- Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off. Under the ".Net Framework 3.5 (Invlucdes .NET 2.0 and 3.0" section
- make sure that "Windows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation" is turned on.
- Also check under ".NET Framerwork 4.x Advanced Services" and under "WCF Services" check to ensure that HTTP Activation is turned on there as well.

This is a picture from that question showing the .net 4.5 change to make.
[Features to turn on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6c3U.png)

If you are using Windows Server try following the first answer to the question regarding how to set up the role using server manager.

Comment: I have managed to get the Web service working on another machine that had Windows 10(IIS 10) installed and your instructions where applicable. However under Windows 7 SP1 I have only the .Net Framework 3.5  option and I get the 500.21 error after I enable HTTP Activation but i am not stuck anymore and should be able to solve the problem on my own. I was looking in the wrong place and would of never figured this out. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm happy that this helped

Comment: That really helped - worked fine under Server 2016 Preview 5 - I think that installed just about every feature by default. After a clean install of Server 2016 Standard this bit was driving me nuts and we all know how stressful that is when working to a schedule :-)

Comment: Installing HTTP activation fixed the 405 error I was getting after I had moved the WCF to a new web server with HTTP activation not installed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, sir! Adding HTTP Activation on Server 2016 was the fix for me too.

Comment: this didn't work for me.  I continue to get 500 errors 'cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation"  see here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74380463/why-is-iis-returning-a-method-not-allowed-error-405-for-a-wcf-service?noredirect=1#comment131309931_74380463