# 404.7 error while browsing .svc file in IIS 8.5

Tags: windows, wcf, iis, iis-8.5, requestfiltering

I am getting a 404.7 error while browsing .svc file in IIS 8.5 (Error message: Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension)

I am able to resolve it by adding this code in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension="." />
             <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

But I am unable to figure out why this error is being thrown in the first place.

I have verified:

1) Request filtering is turned on
2) .svc file is NOT in the list of denied extensions
3) "Allow unlisted file name extensions" is checked in IIS.

With these settings, shouldn't I be able to browse the .svc file without having to add the above code in web.config file? What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue you could try below workaround:

1)Go to  IIS -> Click Website/Application -> select "Request Filtering" -> click "Allow file name Extension" -> add ".svc" -> OK

2)add the belw code in your web.confgig file:

```
<handlers>
   <add name=".svc" verb="*" path="*.svc" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</handlers>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519582

Answer (score 0):

Just for a complement, In order to support WCF extension in IIS, we should enable the below Windows feature.

1. Go to control panel
2. Turn Windows features on or off.

   ---

   [image]

   ---

   Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.